# Amazon EMR - missing ingress rule from EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup on port 9443

Tags: amazon-emr, aws-security-group

I am trying to get my head around this, but cannot figure it out why

1. I have an EMR cluster to be deployed in AWS Private Subnet.
2. I checked the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-man-sec-groups.html).
3. From the above I understood the following:

a. For my EMR *custom* security group, I DO NOT NEED to specify ingress rule for port 9443 i.e. it can be the same as the `ElasticMapReduce-Master-Private`. The following are my inbound/outbound rules for the EMR Managed Security Group for Master/Slave instances (**NOT** Service)

Outbound[image]

Inbound[image]

b. For my custom service security group I can keep it the same as `ElasticMapReduce-ServiceAccess`, I need to specify ingress rule for port 9443 like the following (Terraform):

```
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "allow_tcp_from_master_to_service" {
  type                     = "ingress"
  from_port                = 9443
  to_port                  = 9443
  protocol                 = "tcp"
  security_group_id        = join("", aws_security_group.ml.*.id)
  source_security_group_id = join("", aws_security_group.ml_emr.*.id)

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = false
  }
}
```

But when I deploy this using terraform, I get the AWS error:

```
Error waiting for EMR Cluster state to be "WAITING" or "RUNNING": TERMINATED_WITH_ERRORS: VALIDATION_ERROR: ServiceAccessSecurityGroup is missing ingress rule from EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup on port 9443
```

I am struggling to understand why AWS is saying I need this when I don't? From the documentation it's not clear where this mentioned, so I would appreciate if someone could clarify what's expected here.

Regards,

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @alex            not entirely - this is also possibility when your organisation "Over-manages" AWS - I had to destroy everything using TF destroy and then recreate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have the same SG for master and task instances, you can solve this by using the same SG for both.

Comment: I have same security groups for both Master and Task instances, but i still face the same issue

Answer (score 0):

As per documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-man-sec-groups.html#emr-sg-elasticmapreduce-sa-private

you have to create different/separate Security group rule for TCP port 9443 which is **mandatory** from emr 5.30.0, which allows the communication between master instance's security group to the service access security group.